# Spring JMS config for DefaultDestination

Tags: spring-jms

I have the following config and all seems well, I do not get any errors.
However, when I print jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestinationName(), I get null
Should I see "myQueue"?

```
    <bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="mqConnectionFactory"/>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultDestination">
        <ref bean="destination" />
    </property>

</bean>


<bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="myQueue" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

No; `getDefaultDestinationName()` only returns a value if you set the destination by name (which is later resolved to a destination using a destination resolver). Similarly `getDefaultDestination()` only returns a value if you set it directly, as you did.

Comment: i'm confused, you said it does return a value if it is set directly, and you said i did, but at first you said 'no' to my question? So, should I see null or 'myQueue'?

Comment: I thought I was clear - you set the `defaultDestination` property, in which case `getdefaultDestination()` returns non-null. If you set the `defaultDestinationName` property then `getdefaultDestinationName()` will return non-null. If you set the `defaultDestination` property, then the `getDefaultDestinationName()` will return null and vice-versa. In other words, you get what you set.